# how to override maven-war-plugin source directory

Tags: java, web-applications, maven-2

I had old web application project. Then I added `pom.xml`, and add `maven-war-plugin`. In the old project sources were in `"Java Resources/src"`directory.

In my maven-war plugin I trying overriding default source directorie like this, but not working.

during compilation i see: 
`

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ webproj ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
```

`

my `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exploded</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>    
                <webappDirectory>WebContent</webappDirectory>
                <source>${project.basedir}\src</source>         
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to migrate to Maven, I suggest that you follow the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). Consequently, you should move your source files to `src/main/java`, static resources like .properties files to the `src/main/resources`, and webapp resources like CSS and JavaScript files to `src/main/webapp`.

Answer (score 1):

The Maven-war-plugin use the project source folder, to override the location you must put in your pom like this:

```
<build>

    <sourceDirectory>/Java Resources/src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.build-helper-maven-plugin}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>social/src/main/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        ...
    </plugins>
<build>
```

Comment: doesn't work for me when i try to launch the war:exploded. The plugin try to get the sources in the default source directory

Comment: @herau you override the `sourceDirectory`?, it's a maven property, not a `maven-war-plugin` option, the plugin only is useful if you need more directories.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `warSourceDirectory` in `maven-war-plugin` configuration:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>old/project/source</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```